# Best practice to publish Dialogflow JSON Service Account credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, credentials

I made a CLI application in Python which uses Google Dialogflow.
As the documentation provides, I created a Service Account and downloaded the JSON file. Then I loaded it in Python and the application works.

Now I want to publish my software on GitHub and `pip` but when I load all the files I receive an e-mail from Google that states that I am not managing correctly my credentials. And I agree with that.
The problem is that I do not understand how to manage properly those credentials.

[image: gcp compromised credentials]

Comment: You should require an exported environment variable or config file for your cli app. If neither are provided, throw an error. You'll also want to delete your github repo if your api key is now exposed in plaintext, then request a new key

Comment: How do I provide an exported environment to my code?
repo already deleted

Comment: Use `os.environ`

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 solutions:

- Either anyone can access to your backend, and you don't need a service account, because it's pubilc
- Or, it's private and you don't publish your key (if the secret is known of everyone, the security is useless, make it public!). It's a requirement of the deployment to not commit publicly but to document and to explain how to configure the correct service account to use your app.

Provide more on your context and want you want to achieve to have better pieces of advice. What do you want to protect? Where will you deploy your app? ...